# force output shape for a numpy function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that takes 2 numpy arrays as input and returns a number (real function much more complicated than the example below) :

```py
def the_func(x,y): 
    return np.sum(x)*np.sum(y)
```

```
>>> the_func([2,3,4],[10,11,12])
297
```

So far , so good.

But then

```
>>> the_func([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
441
```

instead of the expected `[36,225]`

So I tried to `vectorize` the initial function :

```
vfunc = np.vectorize(the_func)
```

But

```
>>> vfunc([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
array([[ 1,  4,  9],
       [16, 25, 36]])
```

How can I get that function to return my result in the shape that I'd like to see (in the last example `[36,225]` = `[(1+2+3)*(1+2+3),(4+5+6)*(4+5+6)]`) ?

Comment: `vectorize` passes scalar values from the input arrays to your function.  Your inputs are both (2,3) (when converted to arrays), so the output is also (2,3).  In effect `the_func(1,1)`, `the_func(2,2)` etc.  Also, `vectorize` does NOT speed up your code (compared to a direct iteration).

Comment: Yes was not trying to speed up in that case just writing multiple for loops elegantly

Comment: Aren't you just doing one loop?  `[vfunc(x,y) for x, y in zip(a, b)]`

Comment: Yes I could have zipped everything you're right. My actual code is a bit more complicated and I ended up modifying the function to take the shape into account instead of calling the function multiple times.

Comment: Loop within instead of outside basically

Comment: I'm still stuck on that one though : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552951/convert-float-to-string-numba-python-numpy-array. I know it's not that interesting but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `axis` keyword argument for this to specify along with dimension it should sum. In your example, change your function to this:

```
def the_func(x,y): 
    return np.sum(x, axis=1)*np.sum(y, axis=1)
```

Running it on your sample input gave the result `[36 255]`.

Comment: duh. didn't account for the new shape of the arrays in my actual function. Thank you

Comment: No worries! If the answer solved your problem, please do mark it as the accepted solution :)

Comment: yep waiting to be able to do it